# Windows 7 Home Premium + Domains

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, domain

Colud you help me in joining to a domain with Windows 7 Home Premium and Windows Vista Home Basic? As I know it has no native support for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can with registry edits/updates but this affects the EULA. Are you trying to join an existing domain, or just joining a network (please don't be offended, I'm not trying to ask a rude question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, it's impossible as there is not support for it. You need Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate for Windows 7 and for Vista only Business and Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

None of the windows versions having home or basic type has domain login and remote desktop support...

Comment: and don't forget to add 'starter' to the list :)

Comment: I have seen a windows vista home at one of my friends network and it could connect domain with some registry trick.

Comment: @androbin - We can't help with register hacks.

Comment: @Ramhound Registry hacks are still on-topic for SU.

Comment: @ekaj - Feel free to post the solution if thats the case but I refuse to support registry hacks that override license restritions.